# TCL - trying to execute proc in parallel but getting an odd Java error

Tags: tcl, multiple-processes

I'm following the example from here
https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Execute+in+Parallel+and+Wait
But when I run a simple code like this I get an error: child process exited abnormally and the error is "Error: Could not find or load main class
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:"

```
    for {set i 0} {$i < 5} {incr i} {
        set script {            
            puts hello
        }
        set chan [open |[list [info nameofexecutable] <<$script 2>@stderr]]     
        dict set res $chan command $script
        fconfigure $chan -blocking 0
        lappend background $chan
    }
    
    while 1 {
        foreach chan $background {
            if {[eof $chan]} {
                fconfigure $chan -blocking 1
                if {[set idx [lsearch -exact $background $chan]] >= 0} {
                    set background [lreplace $background $idx $idx]
                }
                catch [close $chan] cres copts
                dict set res $chan result $cres
                dict set res $chan options $copts
            } else {
                puts -nonewline [read $chan]
            }
        }
        if {[llength $background] == 0} {
            break
        }
        after 100
    }
    return $res
}

}
```

I get a similar message when trying to run parallel processes in a slightly different way by running this execute statement in a forloop

```
exec [info nameofexecutable] $variable_of_path_to_script << [list proc_name $param1 $param2] 2>@stderr
```

Comment: What is `[info nameofexecutable]` returning?

Comment: Which implementation of Tcl are you using?

Comment: (It sounds like you're using the Java implementation of Tcl, which requires a more complex argument sequence to run as a subprocess — with things to configure the classpath and so on— to the point where it might be easier to launch a simple `tclsh` instead.)

Comment: Thanks I'll look into tclsh!